# how to use promise on angularjs 1.2.0-rc.3

Tags: angularjs, promise

Now that angular promises no longer auto unwrap:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

how can I use it on this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRiTp2?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can't represent `{{random}}` in HTML since `random` is promise.

Add listener:

```
 $scope.random.then(function(result) {
    alert(result);
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

And this is modified <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iJSd6B?p=preview)</kbd>

So the controller should be like:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      deferred.resolve(Math.random());
    });
  }, 1000);

  $scope.random = deferred.promise;

   $scope.random.then(function(result) {
    $scope.randomNumber = result;
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
});
```

when **HTML**:

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Random Number: {{randomNumber}}!</h1>
 </body>
```

> A **promise** represents a future value, usually a future result 
>   of an **asynchronous operation**, and allows us to define what 
>   will happen once this value becomes available, or when an 
>   error occurs.

*As a side note:*

I would use `$timeout` instead `setTimeout` and `$aplly`

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
  $timeout(function() {
   deferred.resolve(Math.random());
  }, 1000);
```

I suggest you to read this [POST](http://urish.org/angular/AngularPromises.pdf) about promises. It might help.

Comment: Suppose I have a service that returns a random number, but it can be returned from a remote request, or from code. To make both exchangeable, I should always treat as if it is always async?
http://plnkr.co/edit/AqmF2u?p=preview

Comment: async only from delay or $http. In your case you don't need async. See fixed Fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zp70AG?p=preview. Service is only utility.